# Switch focus from one control to another

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, scroll, focus

After I click a label in my treeview, I want the focus to switch to my web browser so the user can scroll up and down without having to click the browser first. This is the code I have right now, but scrolling still scrolls the treeview:

```
if (e.Node.Text == "Sales Screen")
{
    var txt = Properties.Resources.SalesScreen;
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = txt;
    this.ActiveControl = webBrowser1;
}
```

Whats the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Edit: now using this, still not working:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Text == "Sales Screen")
        {
            var txt = Properties.Resources.SalesScreen;
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = txt;
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => webBrowser1.Focus()));
        }
```

Comment: This works, but only every other time. I tried that, and I tried only focusing if `webBrowser.Focused` is false. How would I make it work every time?

Answer (score 3):

The TreeView event you use matters a great deal, it isn't clear which one you use.  TV does not like losing the focus when it fires its events, it will move it back by itself.

Only use the AfterSelect event to execute this code.

---

Yes, the NodeMouseDoubleClick event has this problem.  The workaround is to delay the action of the event handler until *after* the TV has processed the event.  Elegantly one with the Control.BeginInvoke() method.  Like this:

```
    private void treeView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => webBrowser1.Focus()));
    }
```

Comment: How would I do this? right now I'm using the `NodeMouseDoubleClick` event.

Comment: I've added this code into my method, but webBrowser is still only being activated 1/2 times. Have I implemented it correctly?

Comment: Looks okay, very hard to explain a "1/2 times" problem.  If you set the CheckBoxes property to True then see what happens when you set it back to False.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (e.Node.Text == "Sales Screen")
{
    var txt = Properties.Resources.SalesScreen;
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = txt;
    webBrowser1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only works every other time. See my comment on OP

Comment: Adding this.Focus(); also makes it go every other time

Comment: Is there maybe a problem with your initial check (e.node.text == "sales screen")?
Set a breakpoint there and see if it's only passing that logic every other time

Comment: Just tested with a messagebox, the messagebox always pops up